# Button grid layout with twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout, grid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/katGp.jpg)
I want to create a layout like this image but I've problems with % height of boxes and with sticky footer!

```
<!-- HEADER START-->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="vertical-align: middle">
      <div class="col-xs-4"><strong>text left</strong></div>
      <div class="col-xs-4" style="text-align: center">text center</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4" style="text-align: right">text right</div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END HEADER -->

<!-- GRID START -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flush-col" style="height:50% !important">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
            <button class="btn btn-default">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Box Title
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body pheat-body">
                        Box Body
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        Box Footer
                    </div>
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
            <button class="btn btn-default">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Box Title
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body pheat-body">
                        Box Body
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        Box Footer
                    </div>
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
            <button class="btn btn-default">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Box Title
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body pheat-body">
                        Box Body
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        Box Footer
                    </div>
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
            <button class="btn btn-default">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Box Title
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body pheat-body">
                        Box Body
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        Box Footer
                    </div>
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row flush-col" style="height:50% !important">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
            <button class="btn btn-default">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Box Title
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body pheat-body">
                        Box Body
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        Box Footer
                    </div>
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
            <button class="btn btn-default">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Box Title
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body pheat-body">
                        Box Body
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        Box Footer
                    </div>
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
            <button class="btn btn-default">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Box Title
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body pheat-body">
                        Box Body
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        Box Footer
                    </div>
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
            <button class="btn btn-default">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Box Title
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body pheat-body">
                        Box Body
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        Box Footer
                    </div>
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END GRID -->

<!-- FOOTER START -->
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
  </div>
</footer>
<!-- END FOOTER -->
```

- Box height won't size to 50% of container (minus header and footer)

Answer (score 0):

For the height and gutter space issues you are facing, the bootstrap grid structure you used is little faulty and that the reason its not rendering well on your page. Your outer grid layout should look something like below. I have my complete updated code here on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKBraY) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7m6eehc5/1/), whichever you like :-)

**Modified GRID Structure**

```
<!-- GRID START -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row first-row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 bottom-gutter">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 bottom-gutter">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 bottom-gutter">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 bottom-gutter">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 bottom-gutter">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 bottom-gutter">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 bottom-gutter">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 bottom-gutter">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END GRID -->
```

**Updated GRID code**

```
<!-- GRID START -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row first-row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 bottom-gutter">
            <button class="btn btn-default">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Box Title
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body pheat-body">
                        Box Body
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        Box Footer
                    </div>
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 bottom-gutter">
            <button class="btn btn-default">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Box Title
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body pheat-body">
                        Box Body
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        Box Footer
                    </div>
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 bottom-gutter">
            <button class="btn btn-default">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Box Title
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body pheat-body">
                        Box Body
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        Box Footer
                    </div>
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 bottom-gutter">
            <button class="btn btn-default">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Box Title
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body pheat-body">
                        Box Body
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        Box Footer
                    </div>
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 bottom-gutter">
          <button class="btn btn-default">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                Box Title
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body pheat-body">
                Box Body
              </div>
              <div class="panel-footer">
                Box Footer
              </div>
            </div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 bottom-gutter">
          <button class="btn btn-default">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                Box Title
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body pheat-body">
                Box Body
              </div>
              <div class="panel-footer">
                Box Footer
              </div>
            </div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 bottom-gutter">
          <button class="btn btn-default">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                Box Title
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body pheat-body">
                Box Body
              </div>
              <div class="panel-footer">
                Box Footer
              </div>
            </div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 bottom-gutter">
          <button class="btn btn-default">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                Box Title
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body pheat-body">
                Box Body
              </div>
              <div class="panel-footer">
                Box Footer
              </div>
            </div>
          </button>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
<!-- END GRID -->
```

For the sticky footer add the available bootstrap class `navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom`. Update the footer code like so.

```
<!-- FOOTER START -->
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
  </div>
</footer>
<!-- END FOOTER -->
```